# How to set struct field value in which is one of fields of another struct using reflect?

Tags: go, reflection

I'm writing a tool which can help me set any field value of an object, but there's a problem.

I have two structs Player & Card:

```
type Player struct {
    Name string
    IDCard Card
}

type Card struct {
    ID string
}
```

there is the function

```
func setVal(data interface{}, fieldPath []string, val string) {
    // ...
}
```

what the function supposed to do is to set data's specific field value to *val*.
For Example

```
p := Player{
    Name: "Tsuru",
    IDCard: Card{ID: "id"},
}

fieldPath_Name := []string{"Name"}
fieldPath_ID := []string{"IDCard", "ID"}

setVal(&p, fieldPath_Name, "Miku") // set p.Name to "Miku"
setVal(&p, fieldPath_ID, "newID")  // set p.IDCard.ID to "newID"
```

means to set field *Name* to "Miku", and *ID* to "newID" in *IDCard* which is the field of object p.

My method is to recursively get the value and type of every field using golang reflect according to *fieldPath*.

Now the name setting can be successful, but how can I finish the ID setting? IDCard is a struct and is one of the fields of Player.

**Thanks**!

Comment: *"My method is to recursively get the value and type of every field using golang reflect according to fieldPath."* -- Where is that method? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

```golang
rv := reflect.ValueOf(&p).Elem()
rv.FieldByName("IDCard").FieldByName("ID").SetString("newID")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yab71JV_z0j

Comment: My method is not so effective, but now I have some idea thanks to your code :)